# Equivalent to S3 browser-based POST policy with Azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, security, azure-blob-storage

Amazon S3 storage allows you to provide users with the permission to make an upload using a signed POST request, which incorporates the concept of a [POST policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html), allowing you to limit things like filename and size of upload for that request.  You might, for example, want to permit your user to upload a .mp4 file up to 100MB in size.

Does Azure blob storage have an equivalent to this?  As far as I can tell, they recommend that you generate a SAS token for an upload which has no capability of limiting filename and upload size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, no such functionality exists with Azure Blobs.  With Shared Access Signature, you **can't** control the type or size of the content being uploaded using a SAS URL.